# What does the ATM error message "085-CVR CHECK FAILED" mean?

Tags: debit-card, withdrawal, transaction, atm

Today when I tried to withdraw money from the ATM. My transaction was declined, I received this message

The transaction dated 08-Jun-19 20:44:31 through card ending 7123 has been declined due to 085-CVR CHECK FAILED.

What is the cause of this error ?

Please note: I am able to transfer money to and from my account to other accounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The network might have been down.

https://tidalcommerce.com/learn/card-decline-codes

```
Code Number Definition    Practical Definition      What you should do
85 or 00    Issuer System A temporary communication Try it again. 
            unavailable.  error occurred.           If you doesn’t go 
                                                    through, contact your 
                                                    payment processor.
```

Answer (score 1):

CVR failed means Card Verification Request Failed. The Bank manager said it is due to some internal update, it will go away in a few days